# Interpreting a command line: taskkill and ping, specifically "/T >nul", "-w 1000"

Tags: shell, command-line, command, command-line-interface

I'm very new to using command line so this may be such a basic question. 
I am trying to understand the following three lines:

```
    taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T >nul 2>&1
    ECHO Chrome processes killed.
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 5 -w 1000 > nul
```

My current understanding is:
- 1st line: force kill all tasks named "chrome.exe". What does "/T >nul 2>&1" mean?
- 2nd line: displays message
- 3rd line: pings 1.1.1.1, with a wait time of 5 seconds. What does "-w 1000 > nul" mean?

Again, I know this is very basic and wanted to get your help. I googled and read a few guides already to no avail. Thank!
J

Answer (score 0):

With "-w" you set a deadline in seconds, so your ping command will wait a 1000 seconds before it determines a ping to have timed-out.
With "> nul" the output of the ping command is thrown away so it won't show up in any terminals.

Comment: Niels, thank you very much! Can you also help with the first line? What does "/T >nul 2>&1" mean after taskkill?

Comment: /T means you kill the specified process.

Comment: while >nul implies you throw away all regular printed output (stdout) from the taskkill command, with 2>&1 you send printed output indicating errors (stderr) to the regular printed output for you to read.